# The text animation changes after the first slide. WOW.js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, wow.js

I currently have a `carrousel`, in which there is a transition of several slides.
I have an initial animation, which is perfect. As is the desired effect. Consists of the appearance of texts, which are executed one by one, according to the delay of the library.
My problem consists of the following slide, the effect changes, the texts appear by default and perform the animation while the texts are displayed. I want that in all the slides, the animation of the texts is the same as in the first slide.

```
<div class="contenedor_nombre_proyecto">
    <div class="nombre_proyecto_principal">
      <h2 class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0s">titulo</h2>
      <h5 class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">subtitulo</h5> <span class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="2s">holaa</span>
      <p class="textos wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="3s">lorem ipsum dolor sit adem operca</p>
      <p class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="4s">dato 1</p>
      <p class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">dato 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jotasgarcia/72n46nxx/)